# IMG SRC issues in PHP

Tags: php, html, image

I am working on the PHP. I need to pass the value to the image PHP page, and create an image, but it's not working.

This file is the generate php:

```
   if ( $submit == "View Report" )
   {

       header("Content-Type: application/pdf");


        flush();

       // Run HTMLDOC to provide the PDF file to the user...
       // Use the --no-localfiles option for enhanced security!
        passthru("htmldoc --no-localfiles --no-compression -t pdf14 --quiet --jpeg --browserwidth 1100 --webpage ".
          "--color --linkcolor 000099 --bodyfont Sans-Serif --fontsize 8 ".
          " --landscape --header ctl --footer ..: --headfootfont Sans-Serif --headfootsize 8 --size Letter ".
          " --logoimage https://".$urlbase."logo.jpg ".
          " 
          "01:01:".$dataendyear.":12:31:".$dataendyear.":".$dataendmonth.":".$dataendday);

    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

When I check only the image, it shows:

```
  ÿØÿà�JFIF��`�`��ÿþ�>CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v80), default quality
ÿÛ�C�       

 $.' ",#(7),01444'9=82<.342ÿÛ�C         

2!!22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222ÿÀ�Â      ["�ÿÄ����������� 
ÿÄ�µ���}�!1AQa"q2‘¡#B±ÁRÑð$3br‚ 
%&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyzƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š’“”•–—˜™š¢     £¤¥¦§¨©ª²³´µ¶·¸¹ºÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚáâãäåæçèéêñòóôõö÷øùúÿÄ��������   
ÿÄ�µ��w�!1AQaq"2B‘¡±Á   #3RðbrÑ
$4á%ñ&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š’“”•–—˜™š¢   £¤¥¦§¨©ª²³´µ¶·¸¹ºÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚâãäåæçèéêòóôõö÷øùúÿÚ���?�÷ú(¢€9¿ø   –môý+L·Žë^Õâ°†bV!±w<’7dE9 |ÍÀ¸<)âYµ‡Ô4­NÞ;]{ItŠþIhŽõÜ’FÝÑÔdó/ Žäñ_†¦ÖOÕtËˆíuí%Þ[       ¦¢;×kÇ"÷GQ‚GÌ¼{Âž›G}CUÔî#º×µgIoæ„ˆl]©kÙN?3rIì�:#fA!E.c‘øÒy1y¾o–žg÷öŒþtú   (žL^o›å§™ýý£?  Ay_f¸—ËO3ËoŸhÏOZµPÞÇ•Çýsoå@òbó|ß-<Ïïíüèòbó|ß-<ÏïíüéôP<˜¼ß7ËO3ûûF:<˜¼ß7ËO3ûûF:}�Ï&/7ÍòÓÌþþÑŸÎ&/7ÍòÓÌþþÑŸÎŸE�3É‹Íó|´ó?¿´gó£É‹Íó|´ó?¿´gó§Ñ@òbó|ß-<Ïïíüèòbó|ß-<ÏïíüéôP<˜¼ß7ËO3ûûF:<˜¼ß7ËO3ûûF:}�Ï&/7ÍòÓÌþþÑŸÎ&/7ÍòÓÌþþÑŸÎŸE�3É‹Íó|´ó?¿´gó£É‹Íó|´ó?¿´gó§Ñ@òbó|ß-<Ïïíüèòbó|ß-<ÏïíüéôP<˜¼ß7ËO3ûûF:<˜¼ß7ËO3ûûF:}�Ï&/7ÍòÓÌþþÑŸÎ&/7ÍòÓÌþþÑŸÎŸE�3É‹Íó|´ó?¿´gó£É‹Íó|´ó?¿´gó§Ñ@òbó|ß-<Ïïíüèòbó|ß-<ÏïíüéôP<˜¼ß7ËO3ûûF:<˜¼ß7ËO3ûûF:}�Ï&/7ÍòÓÌþþÑŸÎ&/7ÍòÓÌþþÑŸÎŸE�3É‹Íó|´ó?¿´gó£É‹Íó|´ó?¿´gó§Ñ@òbó|ß-<Ïïíüèòbó|ß-<ÏïíüéôP<˜¼ß7ËO3ûûF:<˜¼ß7ËO3ûûF:}�Ï&/7ÍòÓÌþþÑŸÎ&/7ÍòÓÌþþÑŸÎŸE�3É‹Íó|´ó?¿´gó£É‹Íó|´ó?¿´gó§Ñ@òbó|ß-<Ïïíüèòbó|ß-<ÏïíüéôP<˜¼ß7ËO3ûûF:<˜¼ß7ËO3ûûF:}�Ï&/7ÍòÓÌþþÑŸÎ&/7ÍòÓÌþþÑŸÎŸE�3É‹Íó|´ó?¿´gó£É‹Íó|´ó?    ¿´gó§Ñ@òbó|ß-<Ïïíüèòbó|ß-<ÏïíüéôP<˜¼ß7ËO3ûûF:<˜¼ß7ËO3ûûF:}�Ï&/7ÍòÓÌþþÑŸÎ&/7ÍòÓÌþþÑŸÎŸE�3É‹Íó|´ó?¿´gó£É‹Íó|´ó?   ¿´gó§Ñ@òbó|ß-<Ïïíüèòbó|ß-<ÏïíüéôP<˜¼ß7ËO3ûûF:<˜¼ß7ËO3ûûF:}�Ï&/7ÍòÓÌþþÑŸÎ&/7ÍòÓÌþþÑŸÎŸE�3É‹Íó|´ó?¿´gó£É‹Íó|´ó?¿´gó§Ñ@òbó|ß-<Ïïíüèòbó|ß-<ÏïíüéôP<˜¼ß7ËO3ûûF:<˜¼ß7ËO3ûûF:}�Ï&/7ÍòÓÌþþÑŸÎ&/7ÍòÓÌþþÑŸÎŸE�3É‹Íó|´ó?¿´gó£É‹Íó|´ó?¿´gó§Ñ@òbó|ß-<Ïïíüèòbó|ß-<ÏïíüéôP<˜¼ß7ËO3ûûF:<˜¼ß7ËO3ûûF:}�Ï&/7ÍòÓÌþþÑŸÎ&/7ÍòÓÌþþÑŸÎŸE�3É‹Íó|´ó?¿´gó£É‹Íó|´ó?¿´gó§Ñ@òbó|ß-<Ïïíüèòbó|ß-<ÏïíüéôP<˜¼ß7ËO3ûûF:<˜¼ß7ËO3ûûF:}�Ï&/7ÍòÓÌþþÑŸÎ&/7ÍòÓÌþþÑŸÎŸE�3É‹Íó|´ó?¿´gó£É‹Íó|´ó?¿´gó§Ñ@òbó|ß-<Ïïíüèòbó|ß-<ÏïíüéôP<˜¼ß7ËO3ûûF:<˜¼ß7ËO3ûûF:}�Ï&/7ÍòÓÌþþÑŸÎ&/7ÍòÓÌþþÑŸÎŸE�3É‹Íó|´ó?¿´gó£É‹Íó|´ó?¿´gó§Ñ@òbó|ß-<Ïïíüèòbó|ß-<ÏïíüéôP<˜¼ß7ËO3ûûF:}    PEPEPEPPÞÇ•ÇýsoåST7Ÿñåqÿ�\ÛùPÔQE�QE�QE�QE�QE�QE�QE�QE�QE�QE�QE�QE�QE�QE�QE�QE�QE�QE�QE�QE�QE�QE�QE�QE�QE�QE�QE�QE�QE�QE�QE�QE�QE�QE�QE�QE�QE�QE�QE�QE�QE�QE�QE�QE�QE�QE�QE�QE�QE�QE�QE�QE�QE�
çüy\×6þU5Cyÿ�WõÍ¿•�MEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPEPE
```

Comment: please post your desired HTML, the process can be done exactly the opposite. you write in HTML and fill in the blanks with PHP not vice versa

Comment: the html shows what I want.

Comment: What happens if you run the url contained in the src attribute? Does it show an image?

Comment: @EduardoGalván It shows an image with error, and the image doesn't show

Comment: In my opinion, you should lowercase all your HTML tags and attributes, and consistently quote *all* attribute values. It makes the HTML significantly easier to read.

Comment: I use the php file to generate the img file, and use another php file to generate the PDF file. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are showing us the PHP that generates the HTML, but not the PHP that generates the image. That is where the problem must lie.

The content you quoted looks like the beginning of an image file when rendered as text (or as HTML).

By default, PHP outputs a `Content-Type: text/html` header (telling the browser that it is HTML). You need to override that (with the `header()` method) to specify the correct content type for the image format you are using (e.g. `image/jpeg`).

Comment: Hi, thinks for your comment, I add the php file that generates the HTML, and it shows the header() already there.

Comment: I use two php file to generate two imgs in html, and use another php file to generate an pdf file to show these two imgs.

Comment: @kcc — It says it is a PDF, not an image. Browsers don't support PDF files in `<img>` elements.

Comment: but I wanna create the pdf with img, what I need to do?

Comment: Give up? If you want a PDF, don't use `<img>`. If you want to use an `<img>` use an image.

Comment: ok, how about, just create an img in html, because right now the img doesn't work in html, it shows broke up

Answer (score -1):

This is way cleaner.

```
<TABLE WIDTH=50% CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=2 BORDER=0>
    <TR BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF"><TD ALIGN=CENTER>
    <IMG SRC="ewac_cancertcomparisongraph.php?startdate=<?php echo $startdate."&enddate=".$enddate."&dataenddate=".$dataenddate."&size=".$size;?>"></TD></TR></TABLE>
<TABLE WIDTH=1000 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=2 BORDER=0><TR><TD ALIGN=CENTER>
     Figure 1 - 2016 Incident Summary</TD>
</TABLE>
<!-- PAGE BREAK --><BR>
<TABLE WIDTH=50% CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=2 BORDER=0>
    <TR BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF"><TD ALIGN=CENTER>
    <IMG SRC="comparisongraph.php?startdate=<?php echo $startdate."&enddate=".$enddate."&dataenddate=".$dataenddate."&size=".$size;?>"></TD></TR></TABLE>
<TABLE WIDTH=1000 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=2 BORDER=0><TR><TD ALIGN=CENTER>
    Figure 2 - Summary 2015/2016 Comparison</TD>
```

Comment: the url is referring to the php page ewac_cancertcomparisongraph.php, what is the content of that page? does openning the url in a browser show the image? i believe that php page is not well configured

Comment: Thanks for your help, in that page, everything is working well before I update the php version to 5.5. When I finished the update the pdf not working anymore.